# What is the official way to customize, extend and move the API Publisher and API Store out of the WSO2 API Manager server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 reached out to me in Twitter and told me to put a question here if I had one.

My client wants to customize (for now it only means changing the layout of things) the API Publisher and API Store from a WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0.

Since I know that inevitably we will get to the point where the changes are going to be profound and require external libraries for new functionality (we have a library of AngularJS code which I know they will want to use), I want to know:

What is the official, recommended way to customize and extend the web applications for the API Store and the API Publisher? I need to have version control, unit testing, etc.

Is there a way to move these web apps out of the APIM server and into their own server? All our UI applications are hosted in a specific server.

Realistically, how much change can I introduce before make making an awful mess?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new themes and subthemes for API publisher and store UIs. You can refer [docs here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme).

Please note that publisher and store apps are written in [Jaggery](http://jaggeryjs.org). You need a [Jaggery server](http://jaggeryjs.org/quickstart.jag) to host Jaggery apps.

If you want to add more functionality to the UI, you can either write jaggery, or you'll have to write your own web application (maybe with AngularJS or any other). In that case, you can use APIM [REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/apidocs/publisher/) to talk to APIM backend.

Comment: I know that the Publisher and Store apps also use some Java dependencies internally to speak to the backend. How would that fit in moving those apps into their own Jaggery server, out of the APIM server?

Comment: Yes, publisher and store jaggery apps depend on certain apim components. So without them it won't actually work. So I don't think moving these apps is feasible.